# javascript for radio button list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an Radiobutton with (6 items under it). and i have an search button. if user clicks Search button it gets all the result. i am binding the items for Radiobuttonlist using database in .cs file

condition 1: now if user as selected Radiobutton1 [item1] it gets selected. and now if user again clicks on Radiobutton1[item1] then it should get deselected.

how to write an  function onclick if   here. where i need  to  check this condition

either you can provide me the solution in javascript or JQuery any help would be great . looking forward for an solution
 thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. Provides enable/disable functionality on every radio-button on the page. You can alter the selector to match only those radios you are interested in.

But I must tell you that enabling/disabling radiobuttons is counter-intuitive. You really should be using checkboxes for that. As e.g. I when using your site wouldn't expect to be able to uncheck a radiobutton as that is uncommon behavior.

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(i,e) {
    //save initial state
    $(e).data("oldstate", e.checked);
});

$('input[type=radio]').click( function (e) {
    var x = $(this);
    //if the current state is the same as the saved one toggle
    //else don't do anything
    if (this.checked == x.data("oldstate"))
        this.checked = !(this.checked);
    //save current state
    x.data("oldstate", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    /* find _all_ input elements,
       where the attribute "type" = "radio",
       and add an onclick event to them */
    $('input[type=radio]').click( function {
        $(this).selected = !$(this).selected;
        return false;
    });
</script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogroup1" />
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogroup1" />
```

This should only get you an idea how you could handle this.

Comment: if u  can  give the entire coding  . it  would be great.
 i  am new to Javascripting , and Jquery

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't/won't. Two reasons: First, I don't know your (other) code. Second, I'm fine giving someone help, but I don't have time (and I'm not interrested in) doing your work. But if you look at the example I wrote, it won't be that hard to adopt it to your needs. With buying a JavaScript book, maybe a JQuery book too, you'll be able to do the trick for shure! ~Chris